# How can I use the "sort" command on a specific field?

Tags: command-line, sort

In the below example (the original file is much bigger), how can I sort the lines w.r.t. line number of /185/ and /215/?

```
/home/sorbilene/GAMIT_PROCESS/displacement/2/185/gsoln/res_2017-185_2017-186/MEAN.SP80.mit.orbit.res:XYZ Reference position :   4256626.64484  2703340.32982  3894478.42832 (IGb08)
/home/sorbilene/GAMIT_PROCESS/displacement/2/215/gsoln/res_2017-215_2017-216/MEAN.SP80.mit.orbit.res:XYZ Reference position :   4256626.82197  2703340.51128  3894478.40716 (IGb08)
/home/sorbilene/GAMIT_PROCESS/displacement/2/185/gsoln/res_2017-185_2017-186/MEAN.SP80.mit.orbit.res:XYZ Reference position :   4256626.64992  2703340.34367  3894478.43906 (IGb08)
```

The sorted lines should be as follows;

```
/home/sorbilene/GAMIT_PROCESS/displacement/2/185/gsoln/res_2017-185_2017-186/MEAN.SP80.mit.orbit.res:XYZ Reference position :   4256626.64484  2703340.32982  3894478.42832 (IGb08)
/home/sorbilene/GAMIT_PROCESS/displacement/2/185/gsoln/res_2017-185_2017-186/MEAN.SP80.mit.orbit.res:XYZ Reference position :   4256626.64992  2703340.34367  3894478.43906 (IGb08)
/home/sorbilene/GAMIT_PROCESS/displacement/2/215/gsoln/res_2017-215_2017-216/MEAN.SP80.mit.orbit.res:XYZ Reference position :   4256626.82197  2703340.51128  3894478.40716 (IGb08)
```

Answer (score 3):

`sort -t '/' -k 7 -n your_input_file`

Explanation:

- `-t '/'` defines '/' as field separator
- `-k 7` takes the 7th field as sort criteria (the empty field before the first '/' has to be counted, too)
- `-n` specifies a numerical sort.

If you want to keep the order of the input file for all lines where the 7th field is equal you can add (and later remove) a line number as second sort field:

`nl -n rz  your_input_file | sort -n -k 7 -k 1 -t '/' | sed 's/^[0-9]*\t//'`

Explanation:

- `nl -n rz` adds a zero-padded line number before each line
- The `sort` command sorts following the 7th field, and then the line number
- The `sed` command deletes the line number.

Comment: It worked for the above example but if we exchange the line 3 to line 1, the order follows the numeric value of the coordinates not the line number.

Comment: I edited my answer above so that _only_ the field #7 is used for sort.

Comment: the result is still same. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, I see. There is a 'stop' parameter in the key definition of sort, but apparently I did not understand it right. You can see for yourself in `man sort`, under KEYDEF.

Comment: I added an (a little awkward) variant to keep all lines with equal sort field in the initial order (see my answer above).

Comment: The -s for stable sort should keep the identical keys in the input order, but that's hard to tell from the docs.

Comment: @ubfan1 `info coreutils 'sort invocation'` has it more clearly: ```The `--stable' (`-s') option
disables this "last-resort comparison" so that lines in which all
fields compare equal are left in their original relative order.```